# how would $f(T)$ look like if ...

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the result that if $T:V_F\to V_F$ is a linear operator then for any polynomial $f(x)\in F[x],~f(T)$ is a linear operator. Now my question is how would $f(T)$ look like if

1. $f(x)$ is the zero polynomial
2. $f(x)$ is a constant polynomial other than $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Then $f(T)$ is the zero operator, i.e. it sends every vector to the zero vector.
2. If $f(x)$ is the constant polynomial $c$, then $f(T)$ is the operator $cI$, i.e. it sends a vector $\vec v$ to $c\vec v$.

Comment: So combining both we may write, if $f(x)=c,c\in F$ then $f(T)=cI.$ Right?

Comment: @Sriti Correct. The idea is that $T^0=I$.